# NoClassDefFoundError while embedding applet on HTML

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, applet

I'm trying some easy things with JSP and applets.
It's just some really easy applet

```java
package pack1;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class test2 extends Applet
{
   @Override public void paint( Graphics g )
   {
      g.drawString( "Hello!", 10, 10 );
   }
}
```

But I just can't get it working in the browser. In eclipse it's working fine but in  my browser it says `NoClassDefFoundError`.
The important HTML part looks like:

```html
<applet code="pack1/test2.class"  width="200" height="200"></applet>
```

I really tried everything. I put the `test2.class` in every directory, and also tried many variations of the `<applet>` tag but it still won't work.

What should I do?

Picture of the folders:
[image: Picture of the folders]

Answer (score 0):

you need a main method in a java application and an init method in an applet. It's the point of entry.

Answer (score 0):

Html document should be in the folder where the `pack1`, and `test2.class` should be in the `pack1` folder. Everything should be copied to the web root folder.

```html
<applet code="pack1.test2.class"  width="200" height="200"></applet>
```

The value in the code attribute can be of the form `classname.class` or of the form `packagename.classname.class`. See [Applet Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_dev_guide.html).

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError is now an ClassNotFoundException

Comment: the class is not the same dir you run the applet, add classpath .

Comment: i have put the test2.class in every folder so i that it should work in every case (just for triing) :D but i doesn't work

Comment: do you run it in appletviewer or on server?

Comment: i run it with eclipse(works) and with a xampp-tomcat server local (works not)

Comment: do you run tomcat from eclipse or standalone?

Comment: About the **location** of the class, notice that if your applet is in: `http://host/context/applet.html`, you should put your class in: `http://host/context/pack1/test2.class`.

Comment: [Picture of Directorys](http://www.pic-upload.de/view-19402431/applet.png.html) the index.jsp in the Webcontent folder is the one startet with the applet embedded

Comment: try deploying the webapp as exploded archive

Comment: @RomanC You think I'm referring to servlets due to `context` in the URL path?

Comment: @Todeshuegel create a `pack1/` folder under `WebContent/` and place `test2.class` there; making it: `WebContent/pack1/test2.class`.

Comment: @acdcjunior that's a good choice but you should do it every time if you change the class.

Comment: Well, I'm beat. Btw, I added the picture to the question.

Comment: thx @acdcjunior .. so i hve triied every combination i could imagine and also every tip you sayed.. so.. what is wrong? :D i just don't get it

Comment: @Todeshuegel copy pack1/test.class to WebContent/pack1/test.class rebuild, redeploy, restart.

Comment: @Todeshuegel Anything not related to programming, i.e. disabled java plugin.

Comment: @RomanC i also checked everything not related to programming i could imagine.. but no matter what i try it still doesn't work...